# Django: Using Class Based Views How Do I create a form that uses two models?

Tags: django, forms, django-class-based-views

I'm using class based generic views because they are presented in the Django official tutorial. I have two related models:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], blank=True, max_length=15) # validators should be a list



    def __str__(self):
            return self.first_name + self.last_name

class ClientAddress(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    street = models.TextField()
    city = models.TextField()
    state = models.TextField()
    zip_code = models.TextField()
```

I have one view for creating a new Client object:

```
class ClientCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Client
    form_class = ClientForm

    success_url = reverse_lazy('work:client_index')
```

I have one form for each model:

```
class ClientForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']


class ClientAddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ClientAddress
        fields = ['street', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code',]
```

and I have one template for rendering my ClientCreateView:

```
<h1>Create Client Form</h1>
<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {{ sub_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

I want to generate associated Client and ClientAddress objects using a single form OR load both django forms in a single template that gets saved at once OR whatever other methodology is the most correct. How do I do this?

Comment: Can client have more then one address? If so I assume you want to display client form + address formset (for inputting multiple addresses). Is that correct?

Comment: Wouldn't Admin Inlines solve your problem? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects